# How do I perform a TukeyHSD with cluster-robust standard errors?

Tags: r

I currently use the `lm_robust` command in the `estimatr` library to generate cluster-robust standard errors.  I can also use `felm` for this purpose.

I can get all pairwise comparisons of a factor currently like so:

```
aov_model <- aov(outcome~ treatment*condition + education + income + sex + birth + race + trust_daily + turk_experience, data = all_data)
res <- TukeyHSD(my_lm, which = c('treatment:condition'))
as.data.frame(tidy(res,my_lm)) %>% 
    filter(adj.p.value < .05)
```

However, `aov` does not allow cluster robust standard errors.  What is the right way to go about doing this?